# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a .aspx file working on SharePoint.
We are using IE11, jQuery 2.2.3, jQuery UI 1.11.4, Bootstrap 3.3.6
We had this system for around three years by a third party, which we stopped business. And not able to contact anymore.

It was working fine until a few weeks ago suddenly the page is loading forever and showing this error

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference

[Loading page - capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oue1K.png)

I have Googled and it seems like the script is waiting for ConfigurationCube.js to load. But since it's not loading, I think it's waiting forever.

```
/* handles the displaying of all outstanding items requiring approval*/
var TableCreated=0;
var app="";
var teamsArr = [];
var GlobalDivisionsArr = [];

$(document).ready(function(){

//check to see if the Configuration cube Obj Exists and wait until it does
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {       
   if (sessionStorage["ConfigurationCube"] != null) {         

        app = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.ConfigurationCube).AppURL;
        /**CreateLookupSectionForEmployees("My Winners","Kaizen List","#ViewWinnersTable");**/
        //Displayed using the configuration cube.js file
        DisplayUserInformation();
        popDD("kznSearchCategory",JSON.parse(sessionStorage.ConfigurationCube).ListOfCategories);
        IntialPopulationOfApprovedKaizens("","Kaizen List","#kznSearchResultsTable");


        //Initialize date range picker
        /**$("#kznEditToDate").datepicker();*/
        var CubeMin = (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.ConfigurationCube).SubmissionPeriod).split(" ")[0];            
        clearInterval(checkExist);  
    }

}, 500);
```

});

I also tried in IE8, 9, 10, Edge. All not working.
Our company does not allow Chrome or any other browser so we need to get it work in IE..
My current meta tag is like this. Also tried various ways, but did not work.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge; charset=UTF-8">
```

Does anyone have any similar problems?
Any kind of idea is appreciated..

---

When clicking on the error, it directs to ConfigutationCube.js

```
//Tools for other pages

function compareStrings(a, b) {
// Assuming you want case-insensitive comparison
a = a.toLowerCase();
b = b.toLowerCase();                                                                
return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

---

Script snip from SearchKaizen.js

```
function IntialPopulationOfApprovedKaizens(HeadingTitle,ListName,ElementToAppend){

//Get all current data from lists
var GetKaizenPromise = GetList( "Kaizen List",
                                "Id,Nominated_x0020_person, Status, Kaizen_x0020_Title,Division/Id, Team/Id,Division/Title, Team/Title, Name, Financial_x0020_Year, Kaizen_x0020_Category,Quarter",
                                "Division/Id, Team/Id,Division/Title, Team/Title",
                                "Status eq 'Approved'",
                                app);

$.when(GetKaizenPromise).done(function(KaizenSelectionData){

    var EditButton = "";    

    var Results = KaizenSelectionData.d.results;

    //Creates table structure and heading                      
    var DataTableHtml = "";
    var SetVotedBackground = "style='background-color:lightgreen;color:white;'";        

    var DivisionList = [];
    var TeamList = [];
    var YearList = [];

    var DivisionCheck = [];
    var TeamCheck = [];

    if(Results.length > 0){




        for(r=0;Results.length > r;r++){        

        TableCreated++;



        var ResultsName = Results[r].Nominated_x0020_person;
        var KaizenTitle = Results[r].Kaizen_x0020_Title;

        var ResultsTeam = Results[r].Team.Title;
        var ResultsDivision = Results[r].Division.Title;
        var ResultsTeamId = Results[r].Team.Id;
        var ResultsDivisionId = Results[r].Division.Id;


        var ResultsCategory = Results[r].Kaizen_x0020_Category;

        var ResultsStatus = Results[r].Status;
        var ResultsQuarter = Results[r].Quarter;
        var ResultsYear = Results[r].Financial_x0020_Year;


            EditButton = "<p style='cursor:pointer;' class='edititem text-light-blue' data-itemid='"+Results[r].Id+"' data-listname='"+ListName+"'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> View</p>";        
            DataTableHtml += "<tr>"+
                            "<td>"+ResultsName+"</td><td>"+ResultsDivision+"</td><td>"+ResultsTeam +"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+ResultsYear+"</td><td>"+ResultsQuarter+"</td><td>"+KaizenTitle +"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+ResultsCategory +"</td><td>"+EditButton+"</td>"          
                          "</tr>";          

                //Create the drop down box info from all the results
                if($.inArray(ResultsDivision , DivisionCheck ) == -1){
                        // Add to departments list
                        DivisionList.push({"FullName": ResultsDivision,"ID":ResultsDivisionId});
                        DivisionCheck.push(ResultsDivision);    

                        //Keep duplicate of original divisions list
                        GlobalDivisionsArr.push({"FullName": ResultsDivision,"ID":ResultsDivisionId});
                }
                if($.inArray(ResultsTeam , TeamCheck) == -1){
                        // Add to Teams list
                        TeamList .push({"FullName": ResultsTeam,"ID":ResultsTeamId,"Division":ResultsDivisionId});  
                        TeamCheck.push(ResultsTeam);                

                        //Keep duplicates of original list
                        teamsArr.push({"FullName": ResultsTeam,"ID":ResultsTeamId,"Division":ResultsDivisionId});
                }
                if($.inArray(ResultsYear , YearList) == -1){
                        // Add to Year list
                        YearList.push(ResultsYear );                    
                }


            //next Item               
            }

        }else{
        //if there are no results       
            DataTableHtml = "<tr>"+
                                "<td colspan='8'>No results found</td>" +               
                              "</tr>";
        }   



        YearList.sort();
        YearList.reverse();

        TeamList.sort(function(a, b) {
          return compareStrings(a.FullName, b.FullName);
         });

        DivisionList.sort(function(a, b) {
         return compareStrings(a.FullName, b.FullName);
        });

        popDD("kznSearchYear",YearList);

        popDDSearchWithDataAttr("kznSearchTeam",TeamList,TeamList);

        DivisionList.unshift({"FullName": "All","ID":"All"});       //Add All option to division list
        popDDVal("kznSearchDivision",DivisionList);

           //adds items to DOM
        $(ElementToAppend + " tbody").html(DataTableHtml);              
        //Create column match with returned results         

        if (Results.length>0){
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'console';
            $(ElementToAppend).DataTable({  
                "dom": 'ftipr', 
                "responsive": true
            }); 
        }



    $("body").css("overflow","");

    //removes overlayer and loading symbol  
    $("#OverlayFade").addClass("hidden");
    $("#Timer").addClass("hidden"); 
});
}
```

This snip of the script has popDDVal, and it looks like 'DivisionList' 'TeamList' 'YearList' is returning null. Since this is null it can not break from the loading overlayer.

---

I was able to narrow it down to this part.

```
TeamList.sort(function(a, b) {
  return compareStrings(a.FullName, b.FullName);
});

DivisionList.sort(function(a, b) {
 return compareStrings(a.FullName, b.FullName);
});
```

Changed it to this, and it worked. But obviously the sorting is not sorted correctly, but least it works now...

```
TeamList.sort();
DivisionList.sort();
```

Comment: Firstly please copy and paste your actual code in to the question, not an image of it. Secondly, the issue is exactly as the error states; you're calling `toLowerCase()` on an empty/null variable. Without seeing your code we can't help you debug that.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated the script. I'm not sure there it's calling the `toLowerCase()`

Comment: The script you've shown doesn't call it. Perhaps it's in one of the functions, such as `popDD()` or `IntialPopulationOfApprovedKaizens()`. If you double click the error in the console it should take you to the offending line of code - assuming IE does this, it's a terrible browser.

Comment: That seems to be the source then. Either/both `a` or `b` in that function is empty/null. You need to go up the call stack to see where it was called and what values were provided and why they are not what is expected

Comment: Thank you. I did add an alert to both a and b to see what's inside, they were containing array of Department names in lowercases. There was none that was null/empty..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in an anonymous function pass the function name:

TeamList.sort(compareStrings);

or

DivisionList.sort(compareStrings);

Comment: `TeamList.sort(function(compareStrings) {  
    return compareStrings(a.FullName, b.FullName);  
    });  `
 
Thank you. I tried this. But returns `'a' is undefined.`

Comment: `TeamList.sort(compareStrings {
     return compareStrings(a.FullName, b.FullName);
    });` gave me `Expected ')'`

Comment: Perhaps my answer was not clear.  All that is required is to pass in the function name that you have defined already.  Those return statements are unnecessary if I am reading your responses correctly.